# h:form attribute enctype="multipart/form-data" not rendered after post back

Tags: jsf, file-upload, mojarra

I have a form with file upload component:

```
<h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   ... 
   <h:inputFile id="file" value="#{importController.file}" label="File:"></h:inputFile>
   ...
</h:form>
```

and viewscoped backing bean with Part property

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class ImportController implements Serializable {
    ...
    private Part file;
    // getters and setters omitted
}
```

If the user fills everything in the form correctly at first try then the logic works fine. But if there is a validation error (i.e. some text field is missing) after the POST, so the page is being rendered again with posted data and validation messages, the form is rendered without `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute. It causes problems if user corrects the values, chooses the file for upload again and submits the form. An exception "Not a multipart request" is thrown then.

I tried to replace the native jsf h:inputFile with primefaces p:fileUpload but the behaviour is similar. In case of primefaces the exception is not thrown but the UploadedFile property in backing bean is not injected at all because of missing enctype of the rendered form.

I fixed this using javavscript which forces the enctype after the page load, but that is not the correct way. So is this correct behavior or bug or am I missing something fundamental?

There are some parts of the form that are loaded dynamically using ajax, but that is not the case of the inputFile component. However, the missing enctype is not caused by ajax call, but it is missing immediately after the POST when the page is re-rendered and no ajax is called after that.

Wildfly 12.0.0.Final, Mojarra 2.3.3.SP1, Primefaces 6.2

Comment: Tried wildly 14 (assuming it has a newer jsf version)